# Tensorflow で5*5の配列を受け取り、学習して1*5の答えを出力したい

Tags: python, tensorflow

機械学習は入力データの法則、特徴、パターンを見出す仕組みですが、
教師あり機械学習の場合、教師データはどのような意図(法則、特徴、パターン)を持って作られたものでしょうか？

例えば

```
1　0　0　0　0
0　1　0　0　0
0　1　0　0　0　　→　　0　1　0　0　0
0　0　1　0　0
0　0　0　0　1
　入力データ　　　　　　答えデータ

1　0　0　0　0
0　0　1　0　0
0　0　1　0　0　　→　　0　0　0　1　0
0　0　0　1　0
0　0　0　0　1
　入力データ　　　　　　答えデータ
```

がトレーニングのデータとしてあった場合、入力データが

```
1　0　0　0　0
0　1　0　0　0
0　0　1　0　0　
0　0　0　0　1
0　0　0　0　1
```

だった時の答えはどうである可能性が高いのかを学習して求めたいです。

麻雀で、自摸って来た時の１４枚の牌から１枚捨てるというのなので、
完璧な法則はないですが、ある程度の法則はあります。
（説明が難しくて日本語が変で申し訳ありません）

```
import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 25])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 5])

W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([25,5]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5]))

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                         strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,5,5,1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([5 * 5 * 64, 512])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([512])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_conv2, [-1, 5*5*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([512, 5])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([5])

y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for i in range(10000):
  batch = mnist.train.next_batch(500)
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
    x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

Comment: 乱立状態になってしまっているので、前回の質問をクローズしてから新規質問をされてはいかがでしょうか。また、質問のタイトルは聞きたい内容に沿ったものにされたほうが良いと思います。

Comment: クローズとは削除のことでしょうか？あまり書き方が分からなかったのですが、タイトル変更しました。プログラムの書き方教えて頂けると嬉しいです…

Comment: 前の質問を削除されてしまっては他の方に経緯がわかりません。私とあなたのチャット状態になってしまっています。スタックオーバーフローは知識を共有する場との認識ですので、第三者の方から見てもわかることを意識されたほうが良いかと思います。クローズの仕方は回答のチェックマーク✔をクリックです。

Comment: 分かりました！チェックしました。分からなくて消してしまいました…

Comment: @H.Mayu スタック・オーバーフローで「クローズ」というと質問に改善が必要なので回答の受け付けを停止している状態を指します。詳しくは[「質問が『クローズ済み』または『改善待ち』とは?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)をご覧下さい。

Comment: @user20294 投稿に含まれるソースコードや、整形済みのテキストは[選択した上で '{}' ボタンをクリック](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/2069/3054)して整形済みブロックにして下さい。インデントが保持され、`<` などの文字もそのまま使えるようになります。投稿のマークアップに関しては[「Markdown または HTML を使用して投稿を書式設定する方法は?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)もご覧下さい。

Comment: @user20294 質問が解決済みである事を示すには「承認」という操作を行ないます。詳しくは[「自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)をご覧下さい。

Answer (score 4):

(5,5)を入力するのはサンプルで、本当にやりたいのは麻雀の手持ち14牌×種類数34であることは理解しました。

まずコードの方はご提示のコードで何が不都合なのでしょうか？
エラーが出るのでしょうか？訓練が進まないのでしょうか？

また、サンプルの例の方にしてもやはり学習データと答えの関連がないように思えます。
(5,5)に設定する場合は、例えばスートがなく数字が1～5しかないトランプでポーカーをした場合に何を捨てるかという問題にできますが、ご提示の例ですと
[1,2,2,3,5]と持っていた場合2を捨てるのが正解
[1,3,3,4,5]と持っていた場合4を捨てるのが正解
と法則がないように思えます。(前者がストレート狙いで、後者がスリーカード狙い？このような複雑さがあるのであれば学習データはかなりの量必要かと思います。)
ただ、この点に関してはここで議論してもラチがあかないので学習データが本当に正しいかを見直してくださいとしか言えません。
MNISTのコードそのままであり、入力を変えただけならば学習データが妥当ならば(この問題に対してMNISTのネットワークが最適とはいえませんが)それなりの学習は行うはずです。

また本当に設定したい問題は
34種類とりうる14個の入力の中から、適切な1個を選ぶなので(14,34)となりますが、
であれば入力は14*34を(MNISTにならうのであれば)flattenした(476)の大きさになるはずです。
※(34)も萬子、筒子、索子、字牌の(4,9)のtensorに分けた方がいいと思いますが・・・風と三元牌の足りない部分は不使用で

また、答えデータは(34)もしくは(14)の大きさのtensorになるはずです。
(34)⇒34種類のウチどの牌がすてられたか
(14)⇒手持ちの14牌のウチどの牌がすてられたか

tensorflowはニューラルネットワークを自分で設計するPlatformになりますが、
ネットワークの設計自体をご理解されていないように見えます。
まずはコーディングに入らず、ネットワークの勉強をされてはいかがでしょうか。